# Why does my Python turtle shape size decrease when pressing 'shift'

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a turtle in Python so I could increase/ decrease it's size by pressing +/- on keyboard

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(700,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
testing_turtle = turtle.Turtle()


size = 1
def dropsize():
    global size
    if size>1:
        size-=1
        print(size)    # To show the value of size
        testing_turtle.shapesize(size)

def addsize():
    global size
    if size<20:    # To ensure the size of turtle is between 1 to 20
        size+=1
        print(size)
        testing_turtle.shapesize(size)


wn.onkey(addsize,'+')
wn.onkey(dropsize,'-')


wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

> To press the '+' key, I will have to hold 'shift' & press '=' at the same time. The problem is when I release the shift key ( or just press the shift key), it decreases the size value by 1. Why?

Also if I put all these code into a main function:

```
def main():
    import turtle
    ...
    ...
    ...
    wn.onkey(addsize,'+')
    ...
    ...

    wn.mainloop()
main()
```

A error message show up:

```
NameError: name 'size' is not defined
```

I had called 'size' a global variable but why it is not defined now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `'plus'` and `'minus'` to bind the functions to the key-release event of the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> key:

```
wn.onkey(addsize,'plus')
wn.onkey(dropsize,'minus')
```

To solve the `NameError` exception, either place your `size` variable otside your main loop or use the [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) statement instead of `global`:

```
def addsize():
    nonlocal size
    if size<20:    # To ensure the size of turtle is between 1 to 20
        size+=1
        print(size)
        testing_turtle.shapesize(size)
```

Comment: Thanks elegent. Now I know that I've used a wrong key for plus and minus. However I do wonder why the size decreases when I press shift in my original code... I shouldn't have triggered the dropsize function right?

Comment: @Le0: I just asked a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34932365/4594443) about this behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much. Still trying to understand the whole thing but you clearly give me some insight into how...