# Is there a complete list of key event names used by turtle-graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

While playing around with [Python's Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#module-turtle) module, I used some [key events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkey) as the official documentation states:

> `turtle.onkey(fun, key)`
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `fun` – a function with no arguments or None
> - `key` – a string: key (e.g. “a”) or key-symbol (e.g. “space”)

Now the interesting thing is that when you call <sup>1)</sup> the `onkeyrelease()` method and pass a not registered string (like an empty one (`""`), or `"+"`, etc.) as `key` parameter:

```
turtle.onkeyrelease(lambda: print("Got key event while listening to none."), "")
```

No matter what key is pressed by the user, the program outputs "`Got key event ...`", which was by the way the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34860931/4594443).

Unfortunately I can't find more information about this behavior in the documentation ore elsewhere on the internet. So I wonder if there is a complete list of all supported *key-name-strings* used to program key events?

---

<sup>1)</sup> The basic setup used in the question:

```
import turtle
turtle.setup(700,500)
turtleWindow = turtle.Screen()
turtleWindow.onkey(lambda: print("You pressed 'a'"), "a")
turtleWindow.listen()
```

Comment: Read [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/turtle.py), Luke.

Comment: I'm not sure that they are listed directly on turle sources (but i might be wrong). I guess what you are looking for rely on the tkinter implementation, so maybe you could look on that side if you still can't find them.

Comment: @mgc - you are right, looking into the tkinter implementation is a good starting point, since turtle uses it. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I scanned through the [`turtle.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/turtle.py) source and came to the same conclusion as [mgc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932365/is-there-a-complete-list-of-key-event-names-used-by-turtle-graphics#comment57598189_34932365), that the keys are part of `tkinter`, not `turtle`. Not wanting to read through the entire `tkinter` source, I did some googling and found this [full list of keysyms](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) in the Tk docs, as well as this [abbreviated list](https://web.archive.org/web/20190515021108/infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html) for Latin-1 keyboards (it is missing the individual letters, but they are also valid key identifiers, such as `"Q"`). I'm not sure if they are case-sensitive or not, so you'll have to do some experimentation.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I also found the abbreviated list for Latin-1 keyboards -- and they are case-insensitive IMO. But I still wonder why this isn't mentioned in the documentation...

Comment: The link for the abbreviated list is broken.  Fortunately, the link for the full list still works.